# How can I dynamically set the Index in Html and KnockOut JS dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout-mvc

I have the following bit of code. I am using Html in my Razor view and KnockOut JS to bind to my dropdown list.

As you can see, I have programically set the Index as the td is part of a for each and I need the Index to be unique.

The problem I am facing is in the options section, I can only set the Index by actually hard coding it.

Please can someone advise me how I can set it so it reads :

options: viewModel.MyForm.Items()[' + Index() + '].SubItems()[' + Index() + '].MyItemsList(),
value: viewModel.MyForm.Items()[' + Index() + '].SubItems()[' + Index() + '].Id,
Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

```
<td>
<select data-bind="attr: { name: 'MyForm.Items[' + Index() + '].SubItems[' + Index() + '].Id', 
id: 'MyForm_Items[' + Index() + '].SubItems[' + Index() + ']._Id'}, 
options: viewModel.MyForm.Items()[0].SubItems()[0].MyItemsList(), value: viewModel.MyForm.Items()[0].SubItems()[0].Id, 
optionsCaption: 'Select', optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value'"
data-val-required="Required." data-val-number="The field must be a number" data-val="true"></select></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, are you needing to make the TD carry a unique ID to match a portion of your Model?
Otherwise, move the  to before and after your for each loop and build the items inside the dropdownlist.

```
<td><select name='subitems' id='subitems'>
@{foreach (blah in ViewModel.MyForm.Items)
   {
      ...          
   }
}
</select>
```